# How can I configure log4j2.xml file in such a way that it will print out multi line output in one line?

Tags: log4j2

How can I configure log4j2.xml file in such a way that it will print out multi line json output in one line? Or if I have a long message, this message will be printed in one single line

Can I write a following log entry in one single line:

"
WARN  2022-12-01 15:05:01,624 [AsyncHttpClient-7-1] [processor: ; event: ] org.mule.runtime.config.internal.SpringRegistry: Failed to shut down registry cleanly: org.mule.Registry.Spring
org.mule.runtime.api.lifecycle.LifecycleException: org.mule.runtime.api.exception.MuleRuntimeException: Failed to lookup beans of type class java.lang.Object from the Spring registry
Caused by: org.mule.runtime.api.exception.MuleRuntimeException: org.mule.runtime.api.exception.MuleRuntimeException: Failed to lookup beans of type class java.lang.Object from the Spring registry

"

Enpected out put is one long line